# textread error in octave

Tags: matlab, octave

I'm trying to read in a text file with comma delimited data see text of what's in data.txt below but I keep getting an error

feval: function `print_usage' not found

```
text1,eq1=a+b*c
text2,eq2=b+c*d
text3,eq3=c+a*a
```

This the command I use

```
[names,equation]=textread('data.txt', '%s%s', 'delimiter', ',')
```

I have the io package installed and I'm using ubuntu 10.04 with octave 3.2.4

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Something is wrong with your installation. For me it works fine. (I'm on different distro)

Comment: I installed it again from the ubuntu software center and still get the same error but with more info 
>>>error: Unknown property delimiter.
error: Invalid argument specified
>>>error: feval: function `print_usage' not found

Comment: It looks like the old IO package available for download never included the textread.m option and the new textread.m is only compatible with octave 3.4 or greater. http://octave.sourceforge.net/io/index.html which sucks, any body have any work arounds to read text data from a file into arrays on octave 3.2.4? without have to recompile 3.4 and install on multiple different configured machines?